# Elements Jump on Window Resize

Tags: html, css

I have very simple layout that looks like:

[image]

I have an issue with jumping elements when window is resized.

I try to find the solution to avoid this.

Check out the fiddle below:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 12%;
}

.input-text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
}

.right {
 float: right;
   width: 12%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="left">
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
</div>

<input class="input-text" placeholder="Enter Text" />

<div class="right">
<button>Button 3</button>
<button>Button 4</button>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D to better understand the problem, please try to resize the browser window with this simple code snippet

Comment: What do **want** to have happen? What happens *now* is perfectly normal.

Comment: if you need to get a better view when window is resizing you may add media query. or you can use bootstrap grid

Comment: @GayanS.Muthukumarana thanks for mentioning Bootstrap Grid! It's great hint! I will give it a try with simple html `table`, since `td` elements resize nicely.

Comment: @SystemsRebooter most welcome. You can go through https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not entirely clear how you want the elements to behave when you scale. 
I think whatever you want, CSS grid might be the solution for you.

[CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) has a good writeup on css grids.

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 6fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.container2{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70px 70px auto 70px 70px;
}
```

```html
Everything scales:
<div class="container">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <input class="input-text" placeholder="Enter Text" />
  <button>Button 3</button>
  <button>Button 4</button>
</div>
<br/>
Buttons with fixed with:
<div class="container2">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <input class="input-text" placeholder="Enter Text" />
  <button>Button 3</button>
  <button>Button 4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what a wonderful solution! thank you so much. it is much cleaner than <table> wrapper i used. i was fine with any behavior but will use the 2nd one you proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this media query

```
@media (max-width:1128px){
  .left { width: 25%; } 
  .input-text { width: 48%; } 
  .right { width: 25%; }
} 

@media (max-width:542px){
  .left { width: 30%; } 
  .input-text { width: 38%; } 
  .right { width: 30%; }
}
```

Add some more queries for other screens